# Do I need to specify MachineKey for iis instances using shared configuration? And Why?

Tags: iis, web-farm, machinekey, shared-config

I am setting up iis webfarm using shared configuration following this tutorial:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264

In this article, it mentioned how to export iisConfigurationKey to import on other machines. But the article didn't mention whether I need to specify the machine keys instead of using the auto generated ones.

I have tried without export/import the iisConfigurationKey and kept using the auto generated keys on each machine. It seems it is just working fine. However, it feels a little bit odd that how do the machine keys get synced on different machines.

So my question is: do I need to set the machine keys if I am using shared configuration, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. It works fine if you have no encrypted settings, but if you have any, other machines cannot decrypt those. So everything may be working now, but later there may be trouble and you won't remember that you didn't sync them.

Comment: It seems not as you said, I tried connect to each of the nodes, seems all working fine. That's why I'm confused. Is there any way I can see how the data is verified against the keys, e.g. logs or something?